# Force divs in container who are :not(:first-child) to expand to width of :first-child

Tags: html, css

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fyan0dk/). I want the :not(:first-child) elements to not expand past the width of the first child. I have some other things like flex in there, which I have added to show the restrictions I have...

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="item1" class="item">ABC</div>
    <div id="item2" class="item">ABCDEFG</div>
    <div id="item2" class="item">ABCDEFGaaaa</div>
</div>
<div id="right"></div>

body {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
}
#container {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.item:not(:first-child) {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.item {
    background-color: red;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

I don't want to do this in javascript.

[image]

Comment: Set the containers width to auto - depending on the width of the first child, and then set the `item`s that aren't the first child to 100% of the parent width, with a fixed width on the first child?

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. can you try and show a visual representation of what you want.

Comment: There is, I think, no way to do this with CSS. There is no way to select **previous siblings** with CSS to determine the width.

Comment: I have added a photo.

Comment: They just need to expand to the width of the parent div without expanding it.

Comment: You need jquery I'm afraid. The container don't have any way to know it needs to fix  its width to just the first-child and basically ignore the others. with jquery you can set the width of your container to whatever width has the first-child (then add overflow:hidden)

Comment: @Paulie_D: The OP isn't trying to select the first child based on its following siblings. However, they are trying to match the first child based on a certain style, which is also impossible with a selector. Seeing as this is flexbox I'm not sure if there are any workarounds, but I don't think this is about selecting the previous sibling.

Comment: @BoltClock Fair enough...as you say, not the right duplicate (vote retracted) but equally not possible.

Comment: Possible without flexbox?